# Set margin top value in odoo qweb-pdf reporting according to field value

Tags: odoo, qweb

Set margin top value in odoo qweb-pdf reporting according to field value

Eg:  Hello

ab is field se in the model..it can have any value..if it is 4 margin-top is to 4cm ,if it is 7 margin-top to be 7cm....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [t-attf-$name](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#attributes) to define the `style` attribute.

> There are two equivalent syntaxes for format strings: `"plain_text {{code}}"` (aka jinja-style) and `"plain_text #{code}"` (aka ruby-style).

***Example:***
Inherit sale order template and set the margin on `h2` tag

```
<template id="report_saleorder_document_inherit" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//h2" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-attf-style">margin:{{doc.margin}}cm</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```